# Is there a better algorithm for this "Werewolf Prob"?

Tags: algorithm

I have a problem that I am interested in (for a programming contest), and I can't tell if there's a more efficient solution to it than the one I have.

The problem goes like this:

> Bob is a Werewolf. In his "wolf form", Bob is able to run faster than
>   he can in is normal, human form. However, he is able to open doors
>   much faster as a human (due to his hands). He also takes some amount
>   of time to transform back and forth.
>
> If Bob is chasing someone down, and he needs to travel along a hallway
>   with doors, he wants to know what the fastest way to do it would be.
>
> As a wolf, he can run 10 meters per second, while he can only run 4
>   meters per second normally. It takes Bob 8 seconds to open a door in
>   wolf form, and only 1 second normally. It takes him 5 seconds to
>   transform to and from wolf form.
>
> The task is to write a program that, given the distance of the hallway
>   Bob needs to travel, and the locations of all of the doors in the
>   hallway, the shortest time he could cover the distance, along with how
>   many transformations he would make.
>
> Bob always begins in human form.

The way I've solved it is to basically traverse the entire space of possible solutions, and find the one with the least cost.

I feel like there may be a simpler greedy algorithm for solving this problem, but I haven't been able to hit on it.  Any ideas?

Comment: can he run during transformation?

Comment: @firemana Probably not. Vampires don't sparkle, either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My first thought is to consider this as a graph search problem, for which you can use [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). Consider this graph:

```
                          door            door
   HUMAN START-o---------o----o----------o----o-----------------o
               |         |    |          |    |                  } END
WEREWOLF       o---------o----o----------o----o-----------------o
```

Basically, at any given node, you have a sense of state (distance, isWolf), and between any two nodes you have an amount of cost (time). Using Dijkstra's algorithm you could find the shortest time to any given node, with two possible ending nodes.

As noted in the comments, you may observe that the graph is directed: You may only traverse to the right, and it only makes sense to change to a human before a door and a wolf after a door.

Because the problem decomposes to iterative subproblems so well, you might instead think of it from a [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) standpoint, where the subproblem is "what's the quickest time to the far side of `door[n]`, as either a human or wolf, given both times from the far side of `door[n-1]`?"

(I wouldn't call any of these algorithms greedy, because you have two different choices developed at any given moment in time instead of just developing based on the single best-looking solution. There's always a fastest way to any given point, but depending on the shape of the hallway, Bob may have a not-yet-known advantage to being in one form or the other for the remainder of the run.)

Comment: Random note - there's no point in transforming to human form after a door or wolf form before a door.

Comment: @Dukeling Very true, which does reduce the number of edges in the graph or transitions in the dynamic programming solution. You could make a number of other optimizations and heuristics too, such as never considering any run as a human for a distance longer than 66 2/3 meters, but it's a programming contest, and also I wouldn't want to over-optimize a general algorithms question on SO. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for that explanation!  It's not greedy, but your solution is polynomial whereas mine was not.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is reducible to [Shortest Path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem).  There are 2 sets of nodes in the graph for each door, one as a wolf and one as a human.  The distance between the doors is the edge weight.  You can transition from wolf form at a cost (travel from the wolf-graph to the human graph).  The shortest path between 2 locations including transformations will correspond to the shortest path in the combined graphs.  You start out initialized at a door or on a special start node on the "human graph," and finish on an end node as a werewolf.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to do the math so you'll have to figure out the details, but here are my thoughts:

You can only save time by:

Turning from wolf to human to open a door

Turning from human to wolf after opening a door, to run a distance

Basically you only need to make a decision before and after a doorway.

If you are human when you hit a door, go through the door (always faster)

If you are a wolf when you hit a door, check to see if the next hallway is short enough that you want to turn into human before going through the door

If you go through a door as human, check to see if you should turn into a wolf before going the distance

If you go through a door as wolf, you should always stay wolf until the next door

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a greedy solution will look at the shortest/longest runs first, decide which form to go with, and then fill in the rest with whatever form is most expedient.

Overall, though, it seems like you can pre-compute the state transitions, sort them for each doorknob, and choose the lowest value for each.  Or something like that, at any rate.

There's probably an analogy to task scheduling of a mix of I/O- and CPU-bound processes in operating systems, but I can't find a good example of research, unfortunately.